# ¿Cómo agregar otro método a la clase?

Tags: c#

Tengo este código, al cual me piden agregar dos variables más a la clase Mycarro perteneciente al propietario. Ya hice esa parte, todo lo que hay como NombrePropietario y Ciudad,lo hice yo. Lo que me piden es añadir un método a la clase que le permita desplegar los datos del propietario

```
namespace tarea1labprog4
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

  
        String model;
        String color;
        int year;
        String NombrePropietario;
        String Ciudad;

     
       
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el modelo : ");
        model = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el color: ");
        color = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el año : ");
        year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el nombre del propietario: ");
        NombrePropietario= Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite ciudad: ");
        Ciudad= Console.ReadLine();
        Mycarro Carrito = new Mycarro (model, color, year, NombrePropietario, Ciudad);
    
    
        Carrito.Salida();
        
       
    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


public class Mycarro
{

    
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    String NombrePropietario;
    String Ciudad;


    public Mycarro( String model, String color, int year , String NombrePropietario , String Ciudad)
    {
        
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.year = year;
        this.Nombre.Propietario = NombrePropietario<
        this.Ciudad = Ciudad;
    }
  


    public void Salida()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Datos Requeridos: \n "  + model + "" +"\n " + color + " " +"\n " + year +  "" + "\n" + NombrePropietario + "" + "\n" + Ciudad );
        
    }

}
 }
```

Comment: ¿Con respecto a desplegar a que quieres referirte?, Porque en realidad ya estarias enseñando los datos ingresados con  `Salida() `

Comment: @SantiagoPovedaGarcia 1. Realice el siguiente ejemplo que contiene una clase Mycarro, compile, ejecute y pruebe. 
2. Luego agregue dos variables más a la clase Mycarro, perteneciente al propietario
3. Añada un método a la clase que le permita desplegar los datos del propietario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crea un mètodo en la clase `Mycarro` llamado `getPropietario()`

```
public class Mycarro
{

    
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    String NombrePropietario;
    String Ciudad;


    public Mycarro( String model, String color, int year , String NombrePropietario , String Ciudad)
    {
        
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.year = year;
        this.Nombre.Propietario = NombrePropietario<
        this.Ciudad = Ciudad;
    }
  


    public void Salida()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Datos Requeridos: \n "  + model + "" +"\n " + color + " " +"\n " + year +  "" + "\n" + NombrePropietario + "" + "\n" + Ciudad );
        
    }

    public void getPropietario()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Propietario: \n " + NombrePropietario);
        
    }


   }
}
```

al llamar el mètodo `getPropietario()` podràs obtener sus datos.

```
Carrito.getPropietario();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es tan solo desplegar los datos del propietario seria algo asi.

```
public datosSalida(MyCarro Carrito)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre propietario:" + Carrito.NombrePropietario);
        Console.WriteLine("Ciudad:" + Carrito.Ciudad);
    }
```